# Альтернатива AsyncTask для загрузки большого объёма данных

Tags: android, многопоточность

В литературе и статьях в Интернете для получения данных из сети рекомендуется использовать `AsyncTask` внутри `Activity`.

Если объём данных небольшой, это прокатывает на ура. Но,если наоборот, то начинаются проблемы. Особенно, если экран гаснет или поворачивается (что вполне естественно).

Поэтому мне хотелось бы узнать. Есть ли какие-то альтернативные варианты получения большого объёма данных по сети не зависимо от Activity?

Предположительные пути выхода из положения:

- Переместить загрузку  в сервис;
- Использовать `Thread`.

Возможно есть другие решения?

**Важно**: данные идут с REST API.

Comment: Ты можешь использовать executor и калбеки. Или вообще разобраться с RX Java.

Comment: Чем не подходит Download Manager?

Comment: @Style-7, данные идут с REST API.

Comment: Retrofit тут слышали о таком